# Rewrite rule then redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I am trying to rewrite my url

```
http://example.net/?r=123
```

to this one

```
http://example.net/ref/123
```

In my .htaccess this is working using this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ref/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?r=$1 [R=301]
```

But i would like to add another rewrite rule. When the link is like this:

```
http://example.net/?r=123
```

I would like to redirect it to:

```
http://example.net/
```

I tried this rewrite rule but it's not working:

```
RedirectMatch "^/?r=([^/.]+)" "/index.php"
```

Please help. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules to redirect the query string URL to the pretty URL which is more common. Basically redirecting the old url to the SEO friendly one.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+\?r=([^&\s]+)\
RewriteRule ^ /ref/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^ref/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?r=$1 [R=301]
```

If you still want to redirect the query string to index.php instead try this rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+\?r=([^&\s]+)\
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^ref/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?r=$1 [R=301]
```